# Is there a fast way to check a Vec for an error result?

Tags: rust

I'm using Rayon to iterate over a vector, producing a `Vec` of results:

```
let coordinates = &[[38.5, -120.2], [40.7, -120.95], [430.252, -126.453]]
let mut res = vec![];
coordinates
    .par_iter()
    .map(|pair| {
        match (check(&pair[0]), check(&pair[1])) {
            (Ok(v1), Ok(v2)) => Ok([v1, v2]),
            (Err(v), _) => Err(v),
            (_, Err(v)) => Err(v),
        }
    })
    .collect_into(&mut res);
```

I'd like to check `res` for any error values, convert them into `String` and return them using `try!()`

This works, but it's slow and inefficient, considering that I'm allocating a new vector just to aggregate my results or pull out an error:

```
let errcheck: Result<Vec<_>, f64> = res.iter().map(|elem| *elem).collect();
try!(errcheck.map_err(|e| format!("Error: {}", e).to_string()));
```

This problem appears to be Rayon-specific; if I use `.iter()`, I can collect directly into `errcheck` using `collect()` and `map_err()` in the match arms, which I can't seem to do using `par_iter()`.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just collect *directly* into `errcheck`?

Comment: @DK. Maybe that's the reason that Rayon is interesting here... I assume you can't because it's parallel?

Comment: @Shepmaster *blinks* I'm so used to staring at iterator chains I didn't even notice.

Comment: @shepmaster @dk It's rayon-specific in this case; if I use `iter()`, I can collect directly into `errcheck` using `collect()` and `map_err()` in the match arms, which I can't seem to do using `par_iter()`. Anyway, I've noted that it's inefficient because of having to create an extra vector just to hold a result in the format I want.

Comment: @DK. I suppose thats a +1 and a -1 for Rayon. "It looks just like a regular iterator!"

Comment: @DK if it's any consolation, I spent about an hour going WTF when `collect()` didn't work, and didn't even find `collect_into()` until the following day.

Answer (score 3):

If you need only the items that do not fulfil certain conditions,
there is `filter()`:

```
let bounds1 = (-90.0, 90.0);
let bounds2 = (-180.0, 180.0);
let (xmin, xmax) = bounds1;
let (ymin, ymax) = bounds2;

coordinates.par_iter().filter(|pair| {
    let x = pair[0];
    let y = pair[1];
    !((xmin <= x) && (x <= xmax) && (ymin <= y) && (y <= ymax))
}).for_each(|pair| {
    println!("Bad pair: {} {}", pair[0], pair[1]);
});
```

In other words, is map the right operation in the first place.